# How to use i18t for texts in the source code of Angular project?

Tags: angular, internationalization

I am using the i18n features of Angular 4 and building the project successfully with angular-cli in the target language. 
HTML templates are properly translated. However I got some texts in the javascript code.

**What's the recommended way of localizing strings used in js source for
   things like validations?**
Can we expect i18n to come with a solution?

Currently I am using the locale to determine which translation to use.
The Locale gets set from the `ng serve --locale fr` or `ng build --locale fr`

Building/serving like this:

```
ng serve --aot --locale fr  ...
```

and using the locale in the code like this:

```
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
// ...
constructor (@Inject(LOCALE_ID) locale: string) {
}
```

(I was following the great hints on http://blog.danieleghidoli.it/2017/01/15/i18n-angular-cli-aot/)

Comment: Did you consider using ngx-translate (https://github.com/ngx-translate/core)?

Comment: I recommend going this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/61006883/3160597

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `I18nPipe` inside your code:

```
constructor(private translator: I18nPipe) {
    let translatedText = this.translator.transform('Hello');
}
```

Where `transform()` is a method within your `I18nPipe` class that given a `string` parameter translates it. Example:

**i18n Pipe:**

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'i18n',
    pure: false
})
export class I18nPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(public i18nService: I18nService) {
    }

    transform(phrase: any, args?: any): any {
        return this.i18nService.getTranslation(phrase);
    }

}
```

**i18nService:**

```
@Injectable()
export class I18nService {

    public state;
    public data: {};

   getTranslation(phrase: string): string {
        return this.data && this.data[phrase] ? this.data[phrase] : phrase;
    }

    private fetch(locale: any) {
        this.jsonApiService.fetch(`/langs/${locale}.json`)
            .subscribe((data: any) => {
                this.data = data;
                this.state.next(data);
                this.ref.tick();
            });
    }
}
```

In your `i18nService` you are getting the current language in the `fetch()` method and through a custom API service (in my case is `jsonApiService`) you get the data from a es.json, en.json, de.json, etc. *(depending on your `local` parameter)* and in `getTranslation()` you are actually translating a given parameter and returning it's translated value.

**Update 1:**

With this, you can have a file like `es.json`:

```
"hello": "Hola",
"sentence1": "This is the sentence 1",
"goodbye": "Adiós"
```

And this `@Pipe` can be used in the code to apply a translation in your `.component.ts` file like I have shown above *(this is useful for DataTables rendered with Ajax, for example)*.

Or can be applied in your template, simply:

```
{{ 'hello' | i18n }}
{{ this.goodbyeStringVariable | i18n }}
```

Comment: I was more thinking about some compile time replacement like for the HTMLs.
I thought I didn't want to all a Webapi service to get translated texts but rather have a JS file with the translations

Comment: That's exactly what I posted. Check the `fetch()` method, you pass the `locale` as parameter and will load a .js file with the translation. And will get those translations from there. You can use this translation `@Pipe` as a pipe in template or like I showed you in my answer.

Comment: @PeterFromCologne I updated my answer. If you need a more detailed example I can give you tomorrow.

Comment: I will try this and post a comment to let you know. THANKS

Answer (score 1):

We're now (early 2019) using Angular 7 and it seems there's still no support for localizing static strings in TypeScript source files.

So we come up with a simple (if "hacky") way of doing it:

1. Add a hidden HTML element to the template with its content set to the static string from JavaScript code:

```
<!-- string table -->
<span #toolTipText hidden i18n="Tool tip text|Text displayed on the tooltip@@TOOLTIP_TEXT">Do not click this or bad things will happen.</span>
<span #errorOccured hidden i18n="Error notification|Error message displayed when the user ignores the warning on the tooltip@@ERROR_MESSAGE">A very bad thing just happened.</span>
```

2. Reference this hidden element in the code with the `@ViewChild()` decorator:

```
@Component({
  // ...
})
export class BadThingsComponent implements OnInit {

  // "string table" elements for i18n
  @ViewChild('toolTipText') warningMsg;
  @ViewChild('errorOccurred') errorMsg;

  // ...
```

3. Get the string value where it was previously a static string in the code by addressing the decorated class member's `.nativeElement.innerText`:

```
onTryToPreventBadThings(event: CustomEvent) {
    // ...

    this.preventer.messageToDisplay = this.warningMsg.nativeElement.innerText;

    // ...
  }

  onBadThingDidHappen(event: CustomEvent) {
    // ...

    this.notifier.message = this.errorMsg.nativeElement.innerText;

    // ...
  }
```

Comment: It just seemed overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Angular is not supporting this yet. I use a mixture of the default Angular i18n approach because the toolchain is quite nice and a 3rd party tool like [angular-l10n](https://robisim74.github.io/angular-l10n/). The benefit of later is that it is automatically doing what is common for fetching resource files with translations, i.e. falling back  from fr-FR -> fr -> en if no translation is available and offering other convenient functions like placeholders in translations. A manual approach does not offer this.

I'm using this in my service like the following:

```
constructor(translationService: TranslationService) {}
...
foo() {
    this.translationService.translate('httpService.pagingError')
}
```

In the app starter `app.module.ts` I modified the setup a bit to load the default locale from the app. Note the constructor.

```
import { L10nConfig, L10nLoader, TranslationModule, StorageStrategy, ProviderType } from 'angular-l10n';

const l10nConfig: L10nConfig = {
    locale: {
        languages: [
            { code: 'en', dir: 'ltr' },
            { code: 'de', dir: 'ltr' }
        ],
        language: 'en',
        storage: StorageStrategy.Cookie
    },
    translation: {
        providers: [
            { type: ProviderType.Static, prefix: './assets/locale-' }
        ],
        caching: true,
        missingValue: 'No key'
    }
};

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        TranslationModule.forRoot(l10nConfig)
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

    constructor(public l10nLoader: L10nLoader, public localeService: LocaleService,
              @Inject(LOCALE_ID) locale: string) {
        this.l10nLoader.load().then(() => this.localeService.setDefaultLocale(locale));
    }

}
```