# How to implement ng xi18n on array of objects

Tags: arrays, angular, localization, internationalization, interpolation

I am trying to build localization using ng xi18n angular 2 way.As it captures text from template i.e., html files.In my case i am rendering data in html page using *ngFor that is taking up an array from a different file.So how will i implement that,as i cannot give a direct translation for a text in messages.xlf file as that text keep on varying as it is coming from array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is a **limitation** of the current i18n implementation.
Others have requested support for using translations outside of HTML templates.

See this request here:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11405

You can also see this answer to my own similar question:

[How to use i18t for texts in the source code of Angular project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44047676/how-to-use-i18t-for-texts-in-the-source-code-of-angular-project)